# How to check if a integer is a power of some integer?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

Given a integer $n$, we want to know if $n=m^k$ for some $m$ and $k>1$. What is the fastest method? (Suppose the factors of $n$ are not given).

The best method I can think of is to try to calculate $n^\frac{1}{k}$ to a certain precision, for $k$ from $2$ to $\log_2 n$. Determine if $n^\frac{1}{k}$ is a integer by test if $\lfloor n^\frac{1}{k} \rfloor ^k = n$.

Comment: Almost the same question was asked on MathOverflow about a year ago: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/13843/how-to-quickly-determine-whether-a-given-natural-number-is-a-power-of-any-other-n

Comment: The method you wrote down is __very__ fast. (Except there is no need to reraise it to the power $k$, just check the distance to nearest integer, and see if that is within the error tolerance of the $k^{th}$ rooting algorithmP) What are you doing that needs this to be faster?  Whatever your program, it seems unlikely that this is the limiting factor for computation speed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Jonas Meyer said, the [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13843/how-to-quickly-determine-whether-a-given-natural-number-is-a-power-of-any-other-n) post contains all the information.

The problem can be solved in almost linear time by [this paper](http://cr.yp.to/papers/powers.pdf).

Answer (score -1):

Here's a Python 3.8 function that gives a Boolean (True/False) answer to your question: is y a power of x. This can be run in a loop where x can get different values (m) since you don't know the values of both m and k.

```
 def check(x,y):
        if (x == 1): return (y == 1)
        pow = 1
        while (pow < y): pow = pow * x
        return (pow == y)
        #the time complexity here is O(Log (y to base x))
        #we can make this work in O(Log Log y)...
        '''
        The idea is to do squaring of power instead of multiplying
        it with x, i.e., compare y with x^2, x^4, x^8, …etc. If x 
        becomes equal to y, return true. If x becomes more than y,
        then we do a binary search for the power of x between previous
        power and current power, i.e., between x^i and x^(i/2)
        '''
```

I found a coding problem that required this little snippet of code...
Personally, I also needed to know the values of m and k and not just check whether the number n was a power of some number m. What I used was:

```
from math import log
def check(x,y):
    res1 = log(y)//log(x); res2 = log(y)/log(x);
    return [1,res1] if(res1 == res2) else [0];
for _ in range(int(input())): #number of test cases
    x,y = map(int,input().split()) 
    if(x == y): print(1,1)
    elif(x < y and y/x == int(y/x)):
        for i in range(2,int(y/x) + 1):
            if(check(i,int(y/x))[0] == 1): print(1,int(y/x));break
        else: print(0,0)
    else: print(0,0)
```

Here, I was required to find two positive integers a and b such that when x is multiplied by b "a" number of times (basically, n*(b**a)), we get the number y.

printing "0 0" here means there exists no such value of a and b.
for x < y, if y/x is an integer, then there exists some value for a and b
There can, of course, be multiple such values. Like, 2**6 == 4**3 == 8**6.

With respect to your question, here n = x/y. we need to find m and k, which here are b and a respectively.

The simplest solution is 1, int(x/y). That is, putting m = n and k = 1.
Otherwise, we can use m = res1 (from check function, res1 = log(y)//log(x)) and k = i, where i is the iterator (increments on every step of the loop)

```
for i in range(2,int(y/x) + 1):
    arr = check(i,int(y/x))
    if(arr[0] == 1): print(int(arr[1]),i);break
else: print(0,0)
```

Comment: This answer is irrelevant, because the question is about the decision problem existentially quantified over both $k$ *and* $m$.